# iFrame issue in responsive web design

Tags: jquery, css, web

Currently I am doing the responsive web development. The website is completely responsive but we included the ads in the website using iframes. Some ads are like launcher ads or sidekick banner ads. These dynamic ads are not working as expected because of the iFrame.

For example,

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('.rad').each(function(index) {
    var role = $(this).find("div").attr('role');
    if($(this).hasClass('fullwidth-ad')){   
      if(($(this).width() >= 234)&&($(this).width() < 486)) {   
        if(role != 'mobile_leaderboard_ad'){
          $(this).find("div").attr('role','mobile_leaderboard_ad');
          $(this).find("div").attr('class','fix-bottom');                               
          $(this).find("iframe").attr('src','/sites/all/libraries/rad/rad.php?r=mobile_lb');
        }
      } 
      else if(($(this).width() >= 486)&&($(this).width() < 610)) {                              
        if(role != 'banner_ad'){    
          $(this).find("div").attr('role','banner_ad');
          $(this).find("div").attr('class','banner_ad');
          $(this).find("iframe").attr('src','/sites/all/libraries/rad/rad.php?r=tablet_lb');
        }
      } 
      else if($(this).width() >= 610) {                             
        if(role != 'leaderboard_ad'){   
          $(this).find("div").attr('role','leaderboard_ad');
          $(this).find("div").attr('class','leaderboard_ad');
          $(this).find("iframe").attr('src','/sites/all/libraries/rad/rad.php?r=desktop_lb');
        }
      }
    }               
  });
});
```

So any better idea to include ads in responsive web design?

Answer (score 3):

Ads for responsive design can be a real hassle for sure.  In fact, with some ad networks (such as Google AdSense), because you cannot reload ads on a page, you cannot appropriately handle responsive design at all!  The [IAB is supposedly working on it](http://www.iab.net/media/file/ResponsivePerspectiveFinal.pdf). (10 years too late, in my opinion.  It sure would be nice if the business side of technology could keep up.)

What I would recommend is writing your media-query CSS to show/hide divs containing the ads as needed.  Then have some JavaScript code that runs when the page is re-sized.  This code could do something like this:

1. Get the elements associated with ad slots
2. Determine if those elements are set to `display: none` or not.
3. Set up new ads in these slots if they don't already contain ads

You will also want to rate-limit the page re-size.  Use a timeout of 500ms or so that gets reset every page resize.  That way, someone dragging a browser border around won't reload your ads x1000.

Answer (score 0):

you want seamless iframes. disqus uses this technique and it's pretty slick. here's a presentation on it http://benvinegar.github.com/seamless-talk/#/ but you are going to want to pay close attention to slide 33 http://benvinegar.github.com/seamless-talk/#/33